# How to insert visual elements inside the Java text editor of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to add extra visual elements inside the Java text editor of Eclipse, more specifically **on top of classes and methods declarations**. Things like indicators and links.

The best example is what Microsoft has done in Visual Studio with what they call CodeLens:

[image: Visual Studio CodeLens]

The closest solution I can think of is using [Annotations](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors_annotations.htm) (displayed in the rulers) but it's far from the user experience I want to have.

Are there any Eclipse plugins that have done this before?

Any pointers to give me somewhere to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [CodeLens Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/codelens-eclipse).

Eclipse doesn't provide Codelens feature, but it exists [CodeLens Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/codelens-eclipse).

This project provides a [CodeLens extension point](https://github.com/angelozerr/codelens-eclipse/wiki/CodeLens-Extension-Point) to implement your own CodeLens. Today **TypeScript**, **Java JDT** CodeLens and **lsp4e** CodeLens are available. Here a little demo with Java JDT Editor:

[image: JDT CodeLens Demo]

Answer (score 2):

Annotations *are* typically shown in the vertical and overview rulers (left and right), but they're not *limited* to them. Take a closer look at the documentation you linked to, particularly the mentions of [AnnotationPainter](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/AnnotationPainter.html), and then how it uses drawing strategies. I expect you'd need a rather complicated one, and I haven't even thought through how you'd generate the information in the first place, never mind adding it directly to the `Annotation Model` if you're not just going to stash it in a `Marker` on disk.

Of course, some of this looks like information you can already find through **Team**->**Show Annotations** (although that does use the ruler to let you find them by line).